# Cannot access readonly class attributes inside an isolated function in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have two service classes `Astronaut` and `Mission`. Those are interrelated, and I'm trying to make them isolated.
I get the following compilation error

```
invalid access of mutable storage in an 'isolated' function
```

How does `self` instance of `readonly class Astronaut` become mutable? Is there any workaround for handling this situation?

Following is my code.

```
distinct isolated service readonly class Mission {
    public final int id;
    private final string designation;
    private final string? startDate;
    private final string? endDate;
    private final readonly & int[] crewIds;

    isolated function init(int id, string designation, string? startDate, string? endDate, readonly & int[] crewIds) {
        self.id = id;
        self.designation = designation;
        self.startDate = startDate;
        self.endDate = endDate;
        self.crewIds = crewIds;
    }

    isolated resource function get id() returns int {
        return self.id;
    }

    isolated resource function get designation() returns string {
        return self.designation;
    }

    isolated resource function get startDate() returns string? {
        return self.startDate;
    }

    isolated resource function get endDate() returns string? {
        return self.endDate;
    }

    isolated resource function get crew() returns Astronaut[] {
        return self.crewIds.map(isolated function(int id) returns Astronaut {
            return new (id);
        });
    }

    public isolated function includes(int id) returns boolean {
        return self.crewIds.indexOf(id) != ();
    }

}

distinct isolated service readonly class Astronaut {
    private final int id;
    isolated function init(int id) {
        self.id = id;
    }

    isolated resource function get id() returns int {
        return self.id;
    }

    isolated resource function get missions() returns Mission[] {
        return missions.filter(isolated function(Mission mission) returns boolean {
            return mission.includes(self.id); // <=============== line causing compilation error.
        });
    }
}

final readonly & Mission[] missions = [
    new Mission(1, "Apollo 1", (), (), [14, 30, 7]),
    new Mission(2, "Apollo 4", "1967-11-09T12:00:01.000Z", "1967-11-09T20:37:00.000Z", [])
];
```

**Edit :**
Got it working as follows.

```
isolated resource function get missions() returns Mission[] {
        final int id = self.id;
        return missions.filter(isolated function(Mission mission) returns boolean {
            return mission.includes(id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, I have created the following issue to track this, https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/40296. The workaround you suggested should work. We will fix this bug in a future release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was observed in Ballerina versions prior to 2201.6.0 since `self` was not considered to be (implicitly) `final`, which resulted in an error when `self` (of an `isolated` or immutable object) was used as a captured variable in an `isolated` function.

This [has been fixed in 2201.6.0](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/40308) and the sample will no longer result in a compilation error.

In older versions, you could also do the same by assigning to an explicitly `final` variable first.

```
isolated resource function get missions() returns Mission[] {
    final Astronaut astronaut = self;
    return missions.filter(isolated function(Mission mission) returns boolean {
        return mission.includes(astronaut.id);
    });
}
```